# PowerShell - Find and replace multiple patterns to anonymize file

Tags: powershell, replace, find

I need you help. I have a log.txt file with various data in it which I have to anonymize.
I would like to retrieve all these "strings" matching a predefined patterns, and replace these by another values for each of them. What is important is that each new string from the same pattern (and with different value from the previous) should be replaced by the predefined value increased by +1 (e.g. "orderID = 123ABC" becomes "orderID = order1" and "orderID=456ABC" becomes "orderID=order2").
The patterns to search for are more than 20 so it is not possible to put them all in single line.
My idea is:

1. Define "patterns.txt" file
2. Define "replace.txt" file ("pattern" value and replacement value)
3. Search for all "patterns" in the log file, the result will be ARRAY
4. Find the unique entries in that ARRAY
5. Get the "replacement" value for each unique entry in the ARRAY
6. Replace all occurrences in log.txt. The tricky part here is that any occurrence of the same type (but different value from the previous one) needs to be incremented by (+1) in order to be different from the one before.

Example of what I have :

> requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID
> requestID>12345a-12345b-12345c</requestID
> requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID
> requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID
> orderID>012345ABCDE</orderID
> orderID>012345ABCDE</orderID
> orderID>ABCDE012345</orderID
> orderID>ABCDE012345</orderID
> keyId>XYZ123</keyId
> keyId>ABC987</keyId
> keyId>XYZ123</keyId

Desired result:

> requestID>Request-1</requestID
> requestID>Request-2</requestID
> requestID>Request-1</requestID
> requestID>Request-1</requestID
> orderID>Order-1</orderID
> orderID>Order-1</orderID
> orderID>Order-2</orderID
> orderID>Order-2</orderID
> keyId>Key-1</keyId
> keyId>Key-2</keyId
> keyId>Key-1</keyId

For the moment I managed only to find the unique values per type:

```
$N = "C:\FindAndReplace\input.txt"
$Patterns = "C:\FindAndReplace\pattern.txt"
(Select-String $N -Pattern 'requestID>\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}</requestID>').Matches.Value | Sort-Object -Descending -Unique
(Select-String $N -Pattern '<orderID>\w{20}</orderID>').Matches.Value | Sort-Object -Descending -Unique
(Select-String $N -Pattern '<keyId>\w{8}</keyId>').Matches.Value | Sort-Object -Descending -Unique
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion on how to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patterns don't match your sample data. I've corrected the patterns to accommodate the actual sample data.

It seems a simple hash table per type would fulfill the need to keep track of matches and counts. If we process the log file with a `switch` statement using the `-Regex` and `-File` parameters we can work on each line at a time. The logic for each is

- Check if the current match exists in the specific type's match array.

  - If not, add it with it's replacement value (type-count) and increment count.
  - If it does exist, use the already defined replacement value.
- Capture all the output in a variable and then write it out to file when done.

**Create the example log file**

```
$log = New-TemporaryFile

@'
<requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID> -match 
<requestID>12345a-12345b-12345c</requestID>
<requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID>
<requestID>qwerty1-qwerty2-qwerty3</requestID>
<orderID>012345ABCDE</orderID>
<orderID>012345ABCDE</orderID>
<orderID>ABCDE012345</orderID>
<orderID>ABCDE012345</orderID>
<keyId>XYZ123</keyId>
<keyId>ABC987</keyId>
<keyId>XYZ123</keyId>
'@ | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8
```

**Define "tracker" variables for each type containing the count and a matches array**

```
$Request = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$Order = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$Key = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
```

**Read and process the log file line by line**

```
$output = switch -Regex -File $log {
    '<requestID>(\w{6,7}-\w{6,7}-\w{6,7})</requestID>' {
        if(!$Request.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $Request.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Request-$($Request.count)"}
            $Request.count++
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$Request.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    '<orderID>(\w{11})</orderID>' {
        if(!$Order.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $Order.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Order-$($Order.count)"}
            $Order.count++
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$Order.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    '<keyId>(\w{6})</keyId>' {
        if(!$Key.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $Key.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Key-$($Key.count)"}
            $Key.count++
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$Key.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    default {$_}
}

$output | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8
```

The $log file now contains

```
<requestID>Request-1</requestID>
<requestID>Request-2</requestID>
<requestID>Request-1</requestID>
<requestID>Request-1</requestID>
<orderID>Order-1</orderID>
<orderID>Order-1</orderID>
<orderID>Order-2</orderID>
<orderID>Order-2</orderID>
<keyId>Key-1</keyId>
<keyId>Key-2</keyId>
<keyId>Key-1</keyId>
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, that's what I needed. Now as a further step how can I have a file, generated during the anonymization process, in which to have the original data and the corresponding anonymized value (e.g <keyId>XYZ123</keyId>  <keyId>Key-1</keyId>)? With the help of this file/table how could I revert back to the original values? Many thanks!

Comment: In order not to clutter this post up, how about you start a new question referencing this one.

Comment: But a simple answer is you already have the data in each hash table. The match is the key and the replacement is the value.

Comment: Hi Doug, as suggested, I opened the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901869/powershell-store-hash-table-in-file-and-read-its-content. Your feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: Mathias has requested some information. Could you provide that to him?

Comment: There is an issue if 2 strings are on the same line e.g  `<orderID>012345ABCDE</orderID>some text..<keyId>XYZ123</keyId>`. In this case, only the first "match" is replaced, the 2nd remains unchanged as script continues to the next line. How to adapt the script to continue the check on the same line?

Comment: Sounds like a one off that I’d handle manually.

Comment: Hi Doug, :) no, its not one off (there is just one in my example above). I want to run that script on file containing thousands of lines, and a lot of them are very, very long lines, with several "match" conditions (reportId, orderId, keyId, on the same line together with other info). My need is to update/replace all matches, including those on the same line.

Comment: Well if that’s the format of your text why didn’t you post that?

Comment: If you ask a new question, I have a solution for your new requirements.

Comment: The new question has been asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117084/powershell-find-and-replace-multiple-patterns-on-the-same-line-and-store-the-c