# Powershell - Store hash table in file and read its content

Tags: powershell, hashtable

As follow-up, suggested by Doug, on my previous question on anonymizing file (
[PowerShell - Find and replace multiple patterns to anonymize file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740791/powershell-find-and-replace-multiple-patterns-to-anonymize-file)) I need to save all hash tables values in single file "tmp.txt" for further processing.
Example: after processing the input file with string like:

```
<requestId>>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>
```

the tmp.txt file contains:

```
qwerty-qwer12-qwer56 : RequestId-1
```

and this is perfect. The problem is when working with many strings, in the tmp.txt file there are more pairs than there should be. In my example below in tmp.txt I should see 4 times the "RequestId-x" but there are 6. Also when there are 2 or more "match" on the same line, only the first is updated/replaced. Any idea from where these extra lines comes from? Any why the script doesn't continue to check till the end of the same line?
Here is my test code:

```
$log = "C:\log.txt"
$tmp = "C:\tmp.txt"
Clear-Content $log
Clear-Content $tmp

@'
<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>qwertykeyId>Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5</ABC reportId>poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh</msg:reportId>
<requestId>zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56</requestId>
<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>abcde reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-12qw56</requestId>
keyId>Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5</
keyId>Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5</
keyId>Zdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdZdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdLkJpQw</
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
reportId>poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh</msg:reportId>
'@ | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8

$requestId = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$keyId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$reportId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}

$output = switch -Regex -File $log {
    '(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})' {
        if(!$requestId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $req = $requestId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "RequestId-$($requestId.count)"}
            $requestId.count++
            $req.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($req.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$requestId.matches.($matches.1)               
    }
    'keyId>(\w{70})</' {
        if(!$keyId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $kid = $keyId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "keyId-$($keyId.count)"} 
            $keyId.count++
            $kid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($kid.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$keyId.matches.($matches.1)        
    }
    'reportId>(\w{19})</msg:reportId>' {
        if(!$reportId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $repid = $reportId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Report-$($reportId.count)"}
            $reportId.count++
            $repid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($repid.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$reportId.matches.($matches.1)
    } 
    default {$_}
}

$output | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8

Get-Content $log
Get-Content $tmp
```

Comment: the usual way to store data structures for use with PoSh is to use the `Export/Import-CliXml` cmdlets. another is to use JSON ... but the CliXml stuff is designed for saving and the restoring the full sturcture of PoSh objects.

Comment: Can you show us the regex pattern you use for the `<keyId>` tag? Sounds like maybe you've accidentally truncated it

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: the question has been updated with relevant code. Another issue is if there are 2 matching strings on the same line - only the 1st string is updated, the 2nd remains unchanged and the script continues to the next line. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order in which they were found, which I assume you wouldn't if you don't want duplicates, just export them all at the end. I would still keep them in an "object" form so you can easily import/export them. Csv would be an ideal candidate for the data.

```
$requestId,$keyid,$reportid | Foreach-Object {
    foreach($key in $_.matches.keys)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Original    = $key
            Replacement = $_.matches.$key
        }
    }
}
```

The data output to console for this example

```
Original                                                               Replacement
--------                                                               -----------
qwerty-qwer12-qwer56                                                   RequestId-1
zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56                                                   RequestId-2
1234qw-12qw12-12qw56                                                   RequestId-3
Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5 keyId-1    
Zdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdZdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdLkJpQw keyId-2    
poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh                                                    Report-1   
plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As                                                    Report-2
```

Just pipe it into `Export-Csv`

```
$requestId,$keyid,$reportid | Foreach-Object {
    foreach($key in $_.matches.keys)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Original    = $key
            Replacement = $_.matches.$key
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv $tmp -NoTypeInformation
```