# PowerShell - Find and replace multiple patterns on the same line and store the correspondences in separate file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a very large file with thousands of lines, some of the lines are very, very long with various of data. I need to find and replace multiple strings inside that file and several of the strings to be replaced can be on the same line. At the same time the replaced value should increment at each occurrence. In a separate file $tmp I need to keep only the "unique" pairs of "original" value and the corresponding "replaced" value in case of need to revert back the original values. With the great help of Doug Maurer I arrived to the script below which does most of the stuff but still I don't know how to replace the 2nd, 3rd,etc string on the same line and how to keep just the "unique" pairs. Any ideas?

Input:

```
<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>something here.,. reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId
<requestId>zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56</requestId>
<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>something else.,.reportId>poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh</msg:reportId>
```

Desired output:

```
<requestId>RequestId-1</requestId>something here.,. reportId>Report-1</msg:reportId
<requestId>RequestId-2</requestId>
<requestId>RequestId-1</requestId>something else.,.reportId>Report-2</msg:reportId
```

Desired output for $tmp:

```
qwerty-qwer12-qwer56 : RequestId-1
plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As : Report-1
zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56 : RequestId-2
poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh : Report-2
```

```
$tmp = ".\tmp.txt"
@'
Order: Q2we45-Uj87f6-gh65De
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>Ace of Base Order: Q2we45-Uj87f6-gh65De<something else...
<requestId>zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56</requestId>
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-123456</requestId>kljsldjslddsdfdsdsdfff <messageId>1234qw-12qw12-123456</msg
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-123456</requestId>something here.,. reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-123456</requestId>something else.,.reportId>poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh</msg:reportId> uraaa 123 <keyID>poU6Ghk89edfTG78Jk45GrRt23HzW4pl</msgdc
<requestId>zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56</requestId>
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-123456</requestId> abcdef ole ole Order: zxcvbn-zxcv12-zxcv56 abracadabra <keyID>poU6Ghk89edfTG78Jk45GrRt23HzW4pl</msgdc
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-12qw56</requestId>
keyId>Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5</
keyId>Qwd84lPhjutf7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNQwd84lPhjutZ7Nmwr56hJndcsjy34imNPozDr5</
keyId>Zdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdZdjgi76Gho3sQw0ib5Mjk3sDyoq9zmGdLkJpQw</
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
reportId>plmkjh8765FGH4rt6As</msg:reportId>
reportId>poGd56Hnm9q3Dfer6Jh</msg:reportId>
'@ | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8

$requestId = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$keyId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$reportId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}

$output = switch -Regex -File $log {
    '(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})' {
        if(!$requestId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $req = $requestId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "RequestId-$($requestId.count)"}
            $requestId.count++
            $req.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($req.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$requestId.matches.($matches.1)               
    }
    'keyId>(\w{70})</' {
        if(!$keyId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $kid = $keyId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "keyId-$($keyId.count)"} 
            $keyId.count++
            $kid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($kid.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$keyId.matches.($matches.1)        
    }
    'reportId>(\w{19})</msg:reportId>' {
        if(!$reportId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $repid = $reportId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Report-$($reportId.count)"}
            $reportId.count++
            $repid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($repid.$_)" }
        }
        $_ -replace $matches.1,$reportId.matches.($matches.1)
    } 
    default {$_}
}

$output | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Is that XML? PowerShell has built-in XML parsing capabilities - don't use regexes. It can also use .NET's XML parsing capabilities which are more powerful. Check out the `[xml]` type accelerator and the [Select-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

Comment: Also, your example XML isn't valid at all - if you can post something valid, I could probably give more help with actual code.

Comment: No, it's not XML. it's huge log csv file. Just RUN the example above in PowerShell and you will see the issue I described.

Comment: Oh, weird, it looks exactly like XML with namespaces and everything.

Comment: Your current process of outputting to $tmp will output all matches stored each time a new match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Since you may have different mix of data on each lines, I'd recommend this approach.

```
$requestId = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$keyId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}
$reportId  = @{
    Count   = 1
    Matches = @()
}

$text = Get-Content $log

$tmp = ".\tmp.txt"

$output = foreach($line in $text)
{
    if($line -match '<requestID>(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})</requestID>')
    {
        if(!$requestId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $req = $requestId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "RequestId-$($requestId.count)"}
            $requestId.count++
            $req.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($req.$_)" }
        }
        $line = $line -replace $matches.1,$requestId.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    if($line -match 'reportId>(\w{19})</msg:reportId>')
    {
        if(!$reportId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $repid = $reportId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "Report-$($reportId.count)"}
            $reportId.count++
            $repid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($repid.$_)" }
        }
        $line = $line -replace $matches.1,$reportId.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    if($line -match 'keyId>(\w{70})</')
    {
        if(!$keyId.matches.($matches.1))
        {
            $kid = $keyId.matches += @{$matches.1 = "keyId-$($keyId.count)"}
            $keyId.count++
            $kid.keys | %{ Add-Content $tmp "$_ : $($kid.$_)" }
        }
        $line = $line -replace $matches.1,$keyId.matches.($matches.1)
    }
    $line
}

$output | Set-Content $log -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: The "find and replace" works almost perfectly except for this example: `<requestId>1234qw-12qw12-12qw56</requestId>kljsldjslddsdfdsdsdfffmessageId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</msg`. I modified the 1st "match" to search for `(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})`. Do you have a better proposal about the UNIQUE pairs in the $tmp?. Maybe the right answer should go into the other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901869/powershell-store-hash-table-in-file-and-read-its-content?

Comment: unfortunately this could be the case so I cannot count on having always the brackets in the beginning or at the end. For this reason I am searching for the pattern `(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})` wherever it is found. It could happen to have a blanc/space before "messageId" or that it is adjacent to another string as in my example. Why the pattern cannot find the "qwerty-qwer12-qwer56"?

Comment: in the real file, there will be 5 or 6 matches on the same line. And indeed, "messageId"  can correspond to "requestId" and also having the same "orderId". All these could appear or not on the same line. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Last question Doug - what if I don't want to differentiate? Even better to have the same 1rd replaced value e.g. "RequestId-1" for the trio order/request/message. (as soon as they have the same original values) I have to find a way to make it working as in my examples.

Comment: But it would say RequestID-1 for all, is that really what you want? Wouldn't you want it to say RequestID-1, MessageID-1, and OrderID-1?

Comment: I'm leaning toward finding out why the data is so sporadic and inconsistent. You are being asked to achieve crazy results with inconsistent data. :)  But you could run it through another routine with your exported original/replacement data to replace all the duplicates with their replacement strings.

Comment: As soon as the file has the following: `<requestId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</requestId>`  then `<messageId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</messagetId>` and later `<orderId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</orderId>`, the result should be RequestId-1. Simply because the 3 strings are absolutely related. And that's why I want to replace only the `(\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6})` which will allow me later to revert the anonymized data to their original values. e.g. `<orderId>RequestId-1</orderId>` will become again `<orderId>qwerty-qwer12-qwer56</orderId>`

Comment: After many testing I had to recall the "solution" to the question. I have updated the initial hash table with strings which don't update, in particular the 2nd or the 3rd string. The 1st one is always working well. Why?

Comment: Hi Doug, what needs to be updated in the script so the 2nd, 3rd and so on match per line are also detected and replaced? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're still wanting to collect/log them individually, I'm not sure. What I don't understand is all the different sections had different formats previously, now they have identical? That was the entire reason for separate regex matches was the different patterns...

Comment: Once again, in a very big txt file, on a same line I could have several "matches" to be replaced by incremental value. The patterns are different (\w{6}-\w{6}-\w{6}), keyId{\w32},  reportId>{\w19}<</msg:reportId>. Ideally I would like to keep in separate file the original and the replacement value. - your solution for that is perfect. Simply the script does not always detects the following matches on the same line, like in the sample above. "Select-String" or Regex gets all matches per line., but how to build the script ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good luck to you